# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, confluent-kafka-python

stuck with this message:
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'",

and I'm sure if I unzip my confluentlayers.zip then inside it i have the confluent_kafka folder.
Been following multiple examples and always the same results.
Python 3.9
Layer build on my Mac M1/ARM, Layer defined in AWS as ARM, Lambda function defined as ARM based also.
I've tried specifying a version for confluent_kafka when pip install, made no difference
G